# Why won't Zombie Pigmen Spawn in my mob trap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a zombie pigmen farm in the nether, at around y=240, and I can't get any to spawn. The platform is 29 by 29, which is 841 spawn spaces, which should be large enough to get a nice spawn rate. However, I did get a couple to spawn after 10 minutes, and then none for another 15. I made sure I was not standing too close, or playing on peaceful. Another thing is, I checked F3 and saw that there were only 7 entities in the chunk, and 4 were the iron golems that I was looking at.

***Also, the floor is made of white stained clay, NOT lava. I know for a fact that they can spawn on other surfaces than netherrack. A ytuber by the name of Ethoslab has a farm EXACTLY like this, and works great.***

The farm works by zombie pigmen spawning, iron golems killing them, and their drops being collected by a hopper minecart that travels underneath the platforn. I need HELP! PS: Does it have to do with LC values or something like that?[image: The Platform, with me standing a good distance away]

Comment: The floor seems to be made from lava. Mobs can't spawn in lava. And zombie pigmen are immune to it anyway.

Comment: What kind of trap should that be btw? Killing the mobs and destroying the items with them? So you can watch mobs die?

Comment: Are you using any mods or plugins? Changed any gamerules?

Comment: Im using optifine and a texture pack, and nothing else.

Comment: A closer up view of the farm spawning area could help. Also, are zombie pigmen spawning anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be lights around the edge.

For a successful mob farm:

- Valid spawning spaces (solid blocks).
- Dark, 9 or less.
- You must be between 16 and 32 blocks away.
- No other spaces for mobs to spawn.

I have a gold farm that works a little differently to yours, here is a rough plan:

[image]

This is on the roof of the nether, so there are no other spawns up there. This increases efficiency.

Comment: Looks like it's more than dark enough in the middle, white stained clay is solid, and they say there's only 7 entities. The distance could potentially be the problem here, they do look like they're quite far away from it when AFKing.

Comment: @colorfusion it looks dark in the middle, but spawns could be lowered significantly there. Less chance of the pack spawn, so less overall, not just lower numbers - double impact.

Comment: These farms are normally fairly efficient. ~4 blocks around some of the edges lost shouldn't stop spawning to this degree. On second thoughts, does light level actually affect Zombie Pigman spawning? Wiki says it doesn't, and I seem to be getting them spawn on lit platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the difficulty in game slows down the spawning (I watch Ethoslab too so I know that he plays on Hard all the time). And make sure your difficulty is not at Easy.

Although it is said that light levels do not affect the spawning of zombie pigmen, copy Etho's design anyways with the glowstone so you can compare between the two for any differences:

And this is pretty obvious but mistakes happen. Make sure it is not on Peaceful (although you have said that you do see spawns happen).

Otherwise, there should not be a problem here. Can you post a picture with the F3 information? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the floor is netherrack, not lava, water, fences or any other block with the exception of soul sand. For Overworld mobs, (Zombies, creepers, skeletons, etc.) make sure the floor is made from a solid material and the light level is below 7. Keep in mind the floor can be made of any nether material

Comment: Floor is whited stained clay, NOT lava.

Comment: Doesn't have to be nether rack.